# ng-click change class to selected button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

i want to change class btn-white to  btn-primary for the selected Button

```
$scope.SelectedCombination = function (combinationId) {
        $scope.selectedCombination =combinationId;
    };
```

html

```
<button ng-repeat="combination in combinations" class="btn btn-white" ng-model="" value="{{combination.combinationId}}" ng-click="SelectedCombination(combination.combinationId)"  type="button">{{combination.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-class`.don't use any javascript function to set css.

```
<button ng-repeat="combination in combinations" class="btn btn-white" ng-model="x" value="{{combination.combinationId}}" ng-click="SelectedCombination(combination.combinationId);clicked=true;" ng-class="{btn-primary:clicked}" type="button">{{combination.name}}
</button>
```

or you can use best approach:

```
<button ng-repeat="combination in combinations" class="btn btn-white" ng-model="x" value="{{combination.combinationId}}" ng-click="SelectedCombination(combination.combinationId);" ng-class="{'btn-primary':selectedCombination==combination.combinationId}" type="button">{{combination.name}}
</button>
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6NlGuZt6rzBFBwSE1guk?p=preview)

Comment: But I need SelectedCombination () to return the combinationId for my developement

Comment: don't worry.you can execute SelectedCombination () on button click. use edited code.

Comment: sorry remove $scope from html.use this :

ng-class="{btn-primary:selectedCombination==combination.combinationId}"

Comment: problem with - in btn-primary

Comment: use single quote for btn-primary like 'btn-primary'.use edited code and i make plunker for you. just check there.

Comment: ` <button ng-repeat="combination in combinations" class="btn" ng-model="x" value="{{combination.combinationId}}" ng-click="SelectedCombination(combination.combinationId);" ng-class=" selectedCombination==combination.combinationId ? 'btn-primary' :'btn-white'" type="button">{{combination.name}}</button> <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Combinaison 2</button>-->`

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Ng-Class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass%20Ng-Class). Ng-class,allow you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.class